# Days between column dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following columns in PostgreSQL:
[date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjtht.png)

Is there a way to get the number of days between those two columns excluding weekends and a specific list of holidays without creating any new table? I see that it might be possible with generate_series but I can't find the best way to do it.

Comment: Could you please put your code and example in plain text in this topic?

Answer (score 0):

The exact query you are asking for is a litte bit unclear because you didn't tell us whether the amount of days should be built including the first day or not, so as example if the amount should be 1 or 0 for the case date_created = date_updated. Since usually, the first day will also be counted, I assume this in this query to determine the amount of working days:

```
SELECT date_created, date_updated, 
SUM (CASE WHEN EXTRACT (dow FROM dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS workingDays
FROM (SELECT date_created, date_updated, 
GENERATE_SERIES (date_created, date_updated, '1 day'::INTERVAL) AS dt
FROM yourtable) t
GROUP BY date_created, date_updated
ORDER BY date_created;
```

The idea is to build a list of all days between date_created and date_updated and then to count days 1 to 5 only because the weekend days are day 6 and 7 of the week.
In order to also exclude holidays, I think you will require a list of dates that should not be counted. Holidays depend on the region and lots of them differ from year to year, meaning they are not at the same date from year to year. Therefore, I think there is no other way than providing a list of days that should not be counted. So you can extend the first query like this:

```
SELECT date_created, date_updated, 
SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT (dow FROM dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
-SUM(CASE WHEN dt IN (date1,date2,...) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS workingDays
FROM (SELECT date_created, date_updated, 
GENERATE_SERIES(date_created, date_updated, '1 day'::INTERVAL) AS dt
FROM yourtable) t
GROUP BY date_created, date_updated
ORDER BY date_created;
```

As example:

```
SELECT date_created, date_updated, 
SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT (dow FROM dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
-SUM(CASE WHEN dt IN ('2021-01-01','2020-01-01') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS workingDays
FROM (SELECT date_created, date_updated, 
GENERATE_SERIES(date_created, date_updated, '1 day'::INTERVAL) AS dt
FROM yourtable) t
GROUP BY date_created, date_updated
ORDER BY date_created;
```

If you don't want to count the first day (so the amount of days should as example be 0 for date_created = date_updated), just write

```
... - 1 AS workingDays...
```

Working example here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=52a56111f8bd93e0d71669e22b3596eb)